# How to mock Grpc Clients inside GRPC server implementation

Tags: performance, unit-testing, go, grpc, grpc-go

I have a GRPC server that is talking to many other GRPC servers.
So, my server is client for many other GRPC servers
I would like to test my server implementation but I'm stuck on how to mock the GRPC clients.

I have a method from my GRPC server like this:

```golang
func (s UserBackendServer) UpdateUser(ctx context.Context, req *api.UpdateUserRequest) (*api.User, error) {
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, s.userSvcAddr,
        grpc.WithInsecure(),
        grpc.WithStatsHandler(&ocgrpc.ClientHandler{}))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not connect shipping service: %+v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    user, err := api.NewUserServiceClient(conn).
        UpdateUser(ctx, &api.UpdateUserRequest{
        User:                 nil,
        UserId:               "",
    })
    return user, nil
}
```

In this type of implementation, I cannot mock the UserServiceClient because I create one inside the method :(

I have thought about two ways to solve this issue

1. Have the client reference inside the `UserBackendServer` struct

```golang
type UserBackendServer struct {
    projectID string
    userSvcClient api.UserServiceClient
}

func (s UserBackendServer) UpdateUser(ctx context.Context, req *api.UpdateUserRequest) (*api.User, error) {
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, s.userSvcAddr,
        grpc.WithInsecure(),
        grpc.WithStatsHandler(&ocgrpc.ClientHandler{}))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not connect shipping service: %+v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    user, err := s.userSvcClient.UpdateUser(ctx, &api.UpdateUserRequest{
        User:                 nil,
        UserId:               "",
    })
    return user, nil
}
```

With this implementation, I have the side effect of having a continuously active connection to the clients (I have like 10 clients to communicate with). Is it fine in production? Having always-connected clients can it lead to a memory leak or too much concurrents connections?

2. Using methods that get the client as an argument

```golang
func (s UserBackendServer) UpdateUser(ctx context.Context, req *api.UpdateUserRequest) (*api.User, error) {
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, s.userSvcAddr,
        grpc.WithInsecure(),
        grpc.WithStatsHandler(&ocgrpc.ClientHandler{}))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not connect shipping service: %+v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    client := api.NewUserServiceClient(conn)
    updateUser(ctx, req.UserId, req.User, client)


    user, err := s.userSvcClient.UpdateUser(ctx, &api.UpdateUserRequest{
        User:                 nil,
        UserId:               "",
    })
    return user, nil
}

func updateUser(ctx context.Context, userId string, user *api.User, client api.UserServiceClient) (*api.User, error){
    userUpdated, err := client.UpdateUser(ctx, &api.UpdateUserRequest{
        User:                 nil,
        UserId:               "",
    })

    return userUpdated, err
}
```

This seems a little bit cumbersome to write all these little functions and I can't make a unit test of the server function.

The strategy number one is it feasible? do you have experience about limitations or how to retry a failed connections if the connections are maintained in the server struct

Comment: You have a client that makes unary calls to some grpc servers. When you invoke your client constructor it shouldn't instantiate any connections - only when you call updateUser method.
So the best and the only right option here is to pass you client to constructor and mock your dependency.

Comment: @alvery so when I'm doing client := api.NewUserServiceClient(conn) I'm not starting a connection. If I understand correctly write an answer and I'll accept it (after some test). I'll test in the following days. Thank you

Comment: did we get solution to it? i am facing similar issue, where client mock can be unit testedl "howver i am unable to set constructor for client mock, return an error>

Unexpected call to *mock...
xyz_mock.go:65 because: there are no expected calls of the method "xyz" for that receiver